# bat script task scheduler did not show after logined

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

i add a bat script to the Task Scheduler, add the task setting is below:
[image]

and the startup condition is
[image]

when i start up the computer, it will be executed.(i can see its process in the taskmgr). thanks in advance.

but i can't see the black window.(when double click a bat file, it will run in the black windows, right?) i need it show its black window because it has some output information. and in the meantime, the bat is needed to executed when the PC power on(because the PC is a server, i can't set the condition "When the user login".

Comment: as far as I know, a scheduled Task for SYSTEM account does not show up on the screen. If you want to see it, you'll have to use your user's account. But then it would be impossible to run it before login.

Answer (score 1):

Your batch file could redirect the output to a file. When you login, you can view this file or access it remotely via UNC path.